Is it possible to bypass JWT authentication if you know the secret key but not the timestamp?
I found an interesting website with a JWT bypass vulnerability. It uses a simple secret key that can be discovered using brute force, which I did. However, I couldn't exploit the vulnerability because simply changing the id results in the site returning a "Login invalid" error. After some experimentation, I noticed that if you change even one digit in the iat (issued at), nbf (not before), or exp (expiration) fields, even a valid token becomes invalid, and the "Login invalid" error appears immediately. What can be done about this?
JWT request
I tried changing the values of "id", "iat", "nbf", and "exp"

If you get rejected after changing a bit, it probably means you computed some hash (ie. the signature) wrong. If you are absolutely sure that you identified their key, maybe there is some bug in your code that computes the signature: In that case, test your hack: rewrite their security method for yourself, as a test-tool, and then test against it (like in unit testing); by writing tests, you ~double your chance to discover possible bugs on your own side.

Have you tried changing iat, nbf and exp simultaneously? They might be validated together. Also, have you ensured that your bruteforced key actually produces the same signature as in the JWT sample in your possession?

Usually the idea of JWT is to allow underling services to authenticate requests with little or no further requests to upper authorities (reducing check-up efforts on the server and speeding up things); however, the underlings may still take the whole trip to the central authority, to check the token; in the extreme case: if a central server keeps all valid JWT tokens in a central database anyway, signing becomes meaningless.

I already understand what the issue is: the signature is created by hashing payload + secret key. I know the secret key, but I don't know all the payload data, particularly the timestamp. To forge a valid token, in addition to the secret key, you need to know the exact time the token was created, because the timestamp is part of the payload data and it is also hashed.
